# Setting a delay whilst in a for loop Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting a little confused here, not sure if its the monday morning blues! Its just not working :(

What I am trying to achive is:

Fade in each element with the interval set as the rel.

My code for the HTML is (these are all hidden with CSS)

```
    <div id="rpStage">
        <div class="rpItem" rel="500">
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rpItem" rel="4000">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rpItem" rel="6000">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my javascript/jquery.

```
function fadeInrpItem (rpItem, rpDelayTime) {
    rpItem.stop().animate({"opacity" : 1}, 400);
    setInterval(rpDelayTime);
};

function startTheRp () {
        for(var index=0; index < $('.rpItem').length; index++) {

            var rpItem = $('.rpItem').eq(index);

            //Pull in our delay attribute from the div
            var rpDelayTime = rpItem.attr('rel');

            fadeInrpItem(rpItem, rpDelayTime);          
        }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    startTheRp();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your original code is the timing using setInterval, which is currently doing nothing as you are not passing a function to it. Also, your original code is complicating the whole issue.

I think this works how you want

```
delayTime = 0 // initialise delayTime
$('.rpItem') // select all the items we want to work with
    .css({opacity:0}) // for testing - can be commented out
    .each(function(){ // loop through each item
      $this = $(this) // cahce reference of $(this) to improve performance
      delayTime = delayTime + parseInt($this.attr('rel')) // increment delayTime
      $this.data('delay',delayTime) // set current delayTime to item's data (so that asynchronous calls do not use global/updated version when they are called)
      $this // get reference to item as jQuery object
        .delay( $this.data('delay') ) // set the delay as the item's rel attribute
        .animate({"opacity" : 1}, 400) // fade in the item with duration 400
    })
```

It will select all the `.rpItem`'s (then set the opacity to 0 for testing) and loop through them all. Then by refering to `$(this)`, we can operate on each item individually, setting the delay as each item's `rel` attribute, and then animate with duration of 400.

Comment: Excellent this kinda works, however they still all do it at once. How can i get it to work in order, so, div one fades in, then waits 2 seconds, then moves onto div two, waits 2 seconds, e.t.c

Comment: I tested it myself and it does fade in in order. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7MpCW/

Comment: Have a look here for what i mean... http://jsfiddle.net/7MpCW/1/ By the looks of it, all the timers are starting at the same time...

Comment: I see what you mean, I expected this was the intended behavior because of your ascending rel attributes. If you want the delay to be calculated relative, just add the previous values to the new in the loop. I will update...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rpItem').each(function(){
        $(this).animate({"opacity" : 1}, $(this).attr('rel'));
    });
});
```

this will work with `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score -1):

The setInterval function is to be used as follows

```
function fadeInrpItem(rpItem, rpDelayTime) {
    setInterval(rpDelayTime) {
        rpItem.stop().animate({
            "opacity": 1
        }, 400);
    }
};
```